# can not open Qt header files

Tags: c++, qt

The Problem is common but I didn't found any proper answer which satisfy my problem. so let's say it like this, I was working on my laptop using same environment visual studio 2019 same as pc. Every time when I import Qt header file it works while coding but when I copied the project to my pc it shows a lot of errors about header file=>Can not open source file"file name".
Here is the example, `#include <QThread>` is working while implementing but when I copied my project to pc, it shows `can not open source file "QThread"`.
Looking forward for your answers, how to solve it. Debugging and Rebuild code didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, Every time when we build the program the Qt path is already Included in that but when We move some projects from one operating system to another, we have to add additional path in that. Directions to add path in project..

> ->Click on Configuration Properties

```
->Go to C/C++ 
-> Go to General
```

-> Add your Qt Path in `Additional #using Directories` and it will work...